# dsearchn() Command is slowing down my algorithm, Any better Solution? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, search, compare

I am using the following code to calculate altitude.

```
Data = [Distance1',Gradient];

Result = Data(dsearchn(Data(:,1), Distance2), 2); 

Altitude = -cumtrapz(Distance2, Result)/1000;
```

Distance 1 and Distance 2 has different size with same values so I am comparing them to get corresponding value of Gradient to use with Distance 2.

Just to execute these 3 lines the Matlab takes 12 to 15 seconds. Which slow down my whole algorithm.

Is there any better way I can perform above action without slowing down my algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to find alternative method by using interp1 function.

Here is an Example Code.

```
Distance2= [1:10:1000]';
Distance1= [1:1:1000]';
Gradient= rand(1000,1);
Data= [Distance1,Gradient];
interp1(Distance1,Data(:,2),Distance2,'nearest');
```

This function add just 1 second to my original simulation time which is way better then previous 12 to 15 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the first occurance of number Distance2 in the column Data(:,1). You can perform about 3 times faster using find. Try:

```
k = find(Data(:,1) == Distance2,1);
Result = Data(k,2);
```

Here is a timing test, where pow is the length of your data (10^pow for 10000 rows), and fac is the increased speed factor for using find

```
pow = 5;
data = round(rand(10^pow,1)*10);
funcFind = @() find(data == 5,1);
timeFind = timeit(funcFind);
funcD =  @() dsearchn(data,5);
timeD = timeit(funcD);
fac = timeD/timeFind
```

Comment: I tried your approach, however i get "matrix dimensions must agree" error. Distance 1 & Gradient = 17858 x1  & Distance2 = 11531 x 1

Comment: I find one solution which is way faster then dsearchn() function. Result = interp1(Data(:,2),Distance2,'nearest');